# Pointer to struct in C, what is the content?

Tags: c, struct, structure

I was wondering if I have a code like this:

```
struct something{
    int x;
    float y;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct something *p;
    p = malloc(sizeof(struct something));
    p->x = 2;
    p->y = 5.6;
    return 0;
}
```

what's the content of *p (with *) if called somewhere? Is it the address of the structure or what?

Comment: It's the contents of the structure that `p` points to. `p` is the address of the structure.

Comment: The content is in the memory you allocated with `malloc`.

Comment: @Barmar so if I write printf("%ld", *p); it would print the address of the structure right? Thanks for the answer anyway

Comment: Nops, to print the address you want `printf("%p\n", (void *)p);`, without dereferencing, `%p` is the format specifier for a pointer, and a cast to `void *`  is required when printing pointers.

Comment: How did you conclude it? `*p` is of type `struct...`, and cannot be printed using `%ld` specifier (or any standard format specifier).

Comment: @DavidRanieri then can you please give me an example of usage of *p?

Comment: You can't print a structure with `printf()`

Comment: You declared `p` as a pointer variable which should be allocated by `malloc`.  So `*p` means its content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of the usage of `*p` - that is, dereferencing the pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct something {
    int x;
    float y;
};

int main(void) {
    struct something *p;

    p = malloc(sizeof *p);

    p->x = 2;
    p->y = 5.6;

    struct something s;
    s = *p;                         // dereference p and copy into s

    free(p);

    // now check s:
    printf("%d, %.1f\n", s.x, s.y); // prints 2, 5.6
}
```

Comment: So *p is all the the variables' contents of the structure? Actually I had this question because I saw a code using a function toString(*p) and p is a pointer to a structure, what is the return value of that?

Comment: @xcocco _"So *p is all the the variables' contents of the structure?"_ - Yes, that's one way of seeing it. `*p` is the whole object so to speak. _"toString(*p)"_ - I assume that function takes the type of object `*p` is by value (like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/c97eex1sW))  but I'd need to see it to be sure.

Comment: So talking always about my example that function should return "2 5.6" or something like that?

Comment: @xcocco Possibly. It depends on what type `toString` has. It could be `char* toString(struct something v);` and it could then allocate a buffer to put the string in and return that (which the user then has to `free`) - or it could keep a `static` buffer internally and return a pointer to that. Functions taking whole `struct`s by value are uncommon though. One usually just provide a pointer to the instance.

Comment: https://youtu.be/1O-XnbRYJHM you can see toString declared in this video at min 16:41

Comment: @xcocco Hmm, that doesn't look like idiomatic C code. It uses `sizeof` where it doesn't have too and takes `struct block` by value which is rarely what you want.  [Here are two alternatives](https://godbolt.org/z/bjj56Td4f) that I'd like better.

Comment: @xcocco The structure **is** its variables - there is no difference. A structure is just a bunch of variables smooshed together with a sticky label saying what it is.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thank you for your help, I still have a little problem in understanding the whole thing, in your toString functions and the youtube video's function you create a pointer of type unsigned char (which means it's a string), but you use memcpy, when you use it it actually puts in the string only the content of the variables of the structure? I still haven't tried the code so I don't know what it actually does, thanks again for your support anyway

Comment: @xcocco It's not a null terminated string so the name of the function is misleading. What it does is to take a raw copy of the `block` object and put it into an `unsigned char` buffer.

Comment: I'm trying your code on the link but it gives errors about memory leaks

Comment: @xcocco Yes, that would the code in the video do too. The function allocates memory so you need to `free` it when you're done with it.

Comment: can you see the modifications I'm doing on your code?

Comment: @xcocco No, you'll have to click `Share/Short link` and then share the link for that. [Here's an example](https://godbolt.org/z/6vKxsGs1Y) of how the `toString` function could be used. You see that `struct block` is 8 bytes and you can then investigate the individual bytes. One wouldn't need to actually copy the object to do that though. A cast would be enough, like `unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char*) &b;`

Comment: I've just watched your example of usage, but so...it doesn't convert the block into a string...

Comment: No, the `toString` function in the video just takes the raw bytes that makes up a `block` (whatever the definition of a `block` looks like) and puts it in a suitably sized chunk of `unsigned char`s - presumably to perform some operations on it later.

Comment: okay now it's way clearer, thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

`p` is a pointer to `struct something`. `*p` will dereference that pointer to give the struct itself. But, here is the catch: struct (`*p`) is a composite data type, you need to use a `.` operator to get its member.

```
(*p).x = 2;
(*p).y = 5.6;
```

This can also be done without using the indirection operator (`*`) (as you did):

```
p->x = 2;
p->y = 5.6;
```